# I need help importing modules into tests from sibling folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I get an import error "unable to import module" when I try to import a module

File structure

```
src
    modules
    __init__.py
        authenticate_developer
        twttier_importer
    notebooks
        main.ipynb
    unit_tests
        test_authenticate_developer
```

In test_authenticate_developer

```
import requests
from nose.tools import assert_true
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../modules'))
import settings
import twitter_importer #returns import error
import authenticate_developer #returns import error
```

However when I use the same syntax in my notebooks it is successful.

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../modules'))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../'))
import twitter_importer
import authenticate_developer
import settings
```

I have looked at existing answers and I tried them out i.e., removing **init**.py from the root folder and removing or adding **init**.py to the tests folder. None seems to work for me.

Comment: Please post code as text, not images. It makes it easier for us to replicate the problem.

Comment: @Sid thanks for the feedback. I have edited with text

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get someone to help me with these and this is how we tackled it.

```
 src
    modules
    __init__.py
        authenticate_developer
        twttier_importer
    notebooks
        main.ipynb
    unit_tests
    __init__.py
        test_authenticate_developer
```

In test_authenticate_developer

```
import os,sys,inspect
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../modules'))
#This is to access the parent folder in order to import config
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir)

import config
from modules.authenticate_developer import Authenticate
```

I cannot explain why I have to do it differently in the test files but this is my work around